# Mechanical mouse using USB-to-PS/2 Adapter freezes occasionally

Tags: usb, mouse, ubuntu-11.10, adapter, ps2

I am using an AOpen PS/2 mechanical mouse in Ubuntu 11.10 with a [Staples USB-to-PS/2 Adapter](http://www.staples.ca/ENG/Catalog/cat_sku.asp?webid=837523&CatIds=&AffixedCode=WW&=&=&=) with my Intel DP67DE motherboard. The mouse is more comfortable for my hand as it has a lower height than optical mouses. Occasionally the mouse cursor freezes and often I have to unplug it from the USB port and plug it back into another USB port to unfreeze it. This happens with all the USB ports. I've been using the adapter for a few weeks now and this seems to be happening more often recently. What might be happening and is there anything that can be done to fix this?

The most recent output of `dmesg | grep usb` (earlier lines of output truncated due to space limitations on this posting) :

```
[103776.634621] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 38
[103778.878922] usb 1-1.6: new low speed USB device number 39 using ehci_hcd
[103778.987368] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input76
[103778.987485] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.0049: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
[103778.995711] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input77
[103778.995841] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004A: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
[105321.331436] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 39
[105332.265174] usb 1-1.6: new low speed USB device number 40 using ehci_hcd
[105332.373105] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input78
[105332.373232] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004B: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
[105332.381119] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input79
[105332.381257] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004C: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
[105473.423859] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 40
[105484.103033] usb 1-1.6: new low speed USB device number 41 using ehci_hcd
[105484.211069] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input80
[105484.211184] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004D: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
[105484.219340] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input81
[105484.219473] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004E: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
[109165.563603] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 41
[109239.381378] usb 1-1.6: new low speed USB device number 42 using ehci_hcd
[109239.489713] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input82
[109239.489828] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004F: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
[109239.498096] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input83
[109239.498232] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.0050: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
```

Comment: Does this only happen with Ubuntu? can you check with something else, or on another computer?

Comment: I only have Ubuntu on my computer and haven't tried it on another computer. I will try that and see what happens.

Comment: Does any error message appear in `dmesg` when this happens?

Comment: @Renan I've just added the most recent lines of output from `dmesg | grep usb` to my question.

Comment: by mechanical, do you mean a mouse with a ball?

Comment: @Journeyman-Geek Yes. Looking online, it seems people also have had freeze issues with regular USB mice and 11.10.

Comment: This looks pretty much like a hardware issue, rather than an X issue - its disconnecting and reconnecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it sounds like the connection isn't very good, and keeps breaking.

There's a few possibilities here.

Firstly that the mouse itself is failing due to old age - maybe capacitors failed somewhere, or something else. Pop it open (and take the time to clean the insides) and visually inspect it for bloated caps - if so, replace them

I've also heard of issues where some older gear needs more current than USB can provide, though some better quality adaptors handle that.

Geekhack also hits that some adaptors are finicky in their [guide to ps/2 adaptors](http://geekhack.org/showwiki.php?title=PS2-to-USB%20adapters) -get a better PS/2 Adaptor or even a different one.

Comment: I opened the mouse and didn't see anything broken. It was also fairly clean inside as I do clean it from time to time. Just removed some dust in the crevices. I didn't see the 'Staples USB-to-PS/2 Adapter' listed in the guide but it is one of the more expensive ones at $20. So it looks like trying different adapters is next.

Comment: Seems to be working now. Also want to note that I also lifted out and wiped the dust off both sides of the circuit board inside the mouse. There wasn't much dust but that could have made a difference.

Comment: Just froze again so I will investigate further. But overall the mouse is freezing less now.

Comment: fun. I wonder if there was a short, or loose connection somewhere

Comment: Just to clarify, it did freeze once again after I posted my last comment. But overall, the problem is lessened after dusting off the insides. I did securely plug it into the usb port multiple times after unplugging it but it's possible there was a loose connection somewhere internally.

Comment: Just want to add that I no longer have to "plug it back into another USB port to unfreeze it", I can now plug it back into the same port after I unplug it. Also, sometimes I just have to wait a few seconds to see the mouse movement.